# Earbuds with good quality mic

Tags: headphones

I am in search of earbuds that have a good quality mic, that sounds almost professional, but also under 100 USD, i don't care about the quality of the sound nor comfort. 3.5mm

Comment: Shall these attach to the output device by a 3.5mm four-pole RTTS plug, a four-pole 2.5mm plug, Bluetooth 5.0, or Bluetooth 4.0?

Comment: 3.5mm or bluetooth 4.0

Comment: I voted to reopen the question for now. While it is VERY brief, I think it should be possible to make recommendations based on the given requirements. I assume you really mean earbuds, and not headphones/headset. Feel free to elaborate your question a bit more.